# JDK 11 compiling class files fails with OOM exception

Tags: java, out-of-memory, java-11

**[Edit] This is no longer an issue. Did not change anything except using the current JDK11.**

Updated jar dependencies for jdk 11 compliance.
Updated ant to 1.10.x.
Changed ANT_OPTS to use upto 5GB of memory.
Changed the javac task inside build script to use upto 5GB of memory and fork=true.

I get the following error:

```
[javac] Compiling 909 source files to C:\xyz\build\classes
    [javac]
    [javac]
    [javac] The system is out of resources.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [javac]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.relativize(ZipPath.java:226)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer$1.preVisitDirectory(JavacFileManager.java:525)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer$1.preVisitDirectory(JavacFileManager.java:521)
    [javac]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2731)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:520)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getContainer(JavacFileManager.java:316)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:712)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.list(ClassFinder.java:734)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.scanUserPaths(ClassFinder.java:678)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:551)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:299)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder$$Lambda$42/0x00000008000d6040.complete(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.lambda$addRootPackageFor$8(Symtab.java:780)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab$$Lambda$44/0x00000008000d5840.complete(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:355)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:529)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:286)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:301)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:576)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:560)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1066)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:937)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:311)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

---

**Note :** This same setup continues to build fine under java 8

**Update 1:**
Running ant with -verbose and the javac in the build file with verbose provides the search path that is used. Comparing thejdk8 and jdk11 entries :

JDK8 had the following entries that wern't present in jdk 11 search path

```
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\resources.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jsse.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jce.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\charsets.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfr.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\classes
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
c:\jdk1.8.0_152\lib\tools.jar
C:\SourceRepo\xx\yy\
```

The last line is the root of the project where the build.xml exists.
After the search path, there are a bunch of "loading ZipFileIndexFileObject...".
Followed by class file generation of my classes.
Followed by putting them in a jar.

The entries in jdk11 that were missing in the jdk8 search path.

```
C:\jdk-11\lib\modules
```

The above modules doesn't exist.
And then it fails with OOM stacktrace as listed earlier.

---

**Update 2 Oct 17'2018:**
Got an openjdk11 docker image (linux), installed ant on it, mounted my source directory and did an ant build. Worked fine no issues. So it seems like a windows jdk11 issue to me right now.

Comment: Can you try and profile the same, say take a heap dump and look at the cause?

Comment: Will give it a shot. Plan to step through it using the debugger and attaching opoenjdk source files.  Ant verbose does show it get stuck at a the same file. Nothing specific about the file. If I remove it, it gets stuck on another.

Comment: @nullpointer , tried passing in -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\temp\delete using the set ANT_OPTS but not getting the dump.

Comment: Try installing the latest test build of the Java 11 patch. As pointed out in some of the comments of Bug 539536, the current implementation may result in high memory usage. To install the latest build, use this install site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.9-P-builds/P20181001-0525/

Comment: @Pyves : The current exercise is from the command prompt. Eclipse one fails too, but thats not my concern currently. For my CI it needs to run in a shell by teamcity. Will look into the eclipse update for sure.

Comment: @Pyves : I already have the eclipse patch installed.
"Eclipse JDT (Java Development Tools) Patch with Java 11 support for 2018-09 development stream" is already installed"

Comment: Currently it build fine on windows JDK 11. Ran into my question and figured I should provide an update.

Comment: Could it be related to Garbage Collector? The default for Java 8 and Java11 are different. You can try running the Java11 build with -XX:+UseParallelGC